# Download/Save a webpage including all its linked sites

Tags: web, hyperlink, download, save, offline

In Chrome there's this option of saving a complete webpage. I would like to save a complete webpage but that the pages which are linked should also be saved. Is this possible? I.e. I want to go one step further than simply saving the page I'm looking at. Is it possible to go two steps further? I.e. saving all the linked pages in the linked pages? Is it possible to generalized this to N-steps? I realize this would need a lot of memory space, but is there a code available to do this task?

Comment: you can do this with [wget](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Wget) example wget -r hxxp://url and you just need a little work in html to point correct file.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for the tip!